# Scrapy Splash + Crawlera in Linux always get 503 service unavailable error

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render, crawlera

When I use Scrapy Splash + Crawlera in my Linux server, it always gets 503 errors. It works just fine in Windows. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, it doesn't work if I set `SPLASH_URL = '0.0.0.0:8050'`. I have to set it using the IP instead of localhost IP, like `SPLASH_URL = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8050'`